# Depth render artifacts

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl

I am depth only rendering scene to different frame buffer, the problem is a bit hard to explain but as you can see in the image the depth map it is actually suffering from grid like artifacts. Do you have any idea what can be the source of this ?

here is the code for fb creation:

```
    self.shadowTexture = glGenTextures(1);        
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.shadowTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP );

    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, None);

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    self.fbo = glGenFramebuffers(1)
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, self.fbo)
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.shadowTexture, 0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem most likely comes from the fact that your projection matrix has too much seperation between near and far planes (meaning close together pixels are suffering floating point accuracy issues).  Shrink the gap between the 2 planes and that should solve your Z-fighting issues.

Comment: thank you Goz, that seems to be it. I was actually working on shadow maps, using sane values for light and camera projection matrices is tricky.